# How long do items persist on the ground outside?

Tags: stardew-valley

I've occasionally had to leave an item, like wood or stones, uncollected on the ground due to a full inventory. I notice that they persist between area changes (so I can cut down a tree in the Backwoods, run home and clear out my inventory, then go collect the remaining items), and I once picked up some hardwood I'd forgotten about a day or two after cutting it.

How long to items persist outside on the ground? They persist at least a day, but for how long in general: a set number of days, the whole season, … or indefinitely?

Answer (score 15):

Items will disappear over night if they are left on the ground. I just finished testing this:

I placed one item from my inventory on the ground. I also harvested one item from a resource and let it stay on the ground. Then went directly to my bed to sleep and both items were gone the next morning.

I was also curious if crops were an exception, but they disappeared over night as well.

I tried this inside the farm and outside the farm

Comment: Science is good, but this science is incomplete as it doesn't explain the hardwood I picked up a couple days after cutting it.

Comment: It's possible that certain items may have exception properties, but as a general rule I think the above is correct. You would need to experiment with hardwood specifically if this was the case since I wasn't able to get any item to remain through the night. I am curious now though